# Parameter space for a theory

Tags: graphics, parameters

I was trying to learn to make plots of parameter spaces.

For example, if I have a theory with one free parameter

$$g(z)=\alpha(1+z)^2$$

I know that you can plot  the function ass function of $z$, and get something like this ($\alpha=1$)

[image]

But I have other parameter that is function of $\alpha$, let's say $\Omega(z)=\alpha^2/(1+z)$. And I have seen that some [people](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.07536.pdf) make this kind of plots, this are called parameter space plots, you know how to make them?

[image]

Comment: You're looking for `ContourPlot`.  Look it up in the documentation for details and options, but something like `ContourPlot[Omega[z], {z, 1, 5}, {alpha, 0.95, 1}]`.

Comment: Thank you. May be this is the answer, but you know that is the meaning of the bar in the rigth in this code?  
```ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]"```